# How does one define a widget of type editable-list with validation?

Tags: elisp, error-handling, widget

I create my widget with the following code:

```
(widget-create 'editable-list
                   :entry-format "%i %d %v"
                   :value '("")
                   '(editable-field
                     :valid-regexp "\\(?:ftp://\\|http\\(?:s?://\\)\\|magnet:\\)"
                     :error "Url does not match supported type."
                     :value ""))
```

Unfortunately input validation is not working.
How does one define a widget of type editable-list with validation?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that input validation of top-level widgets happens automatically.  Neither the info manual nor the source code suggest otherwise.

Composite widgets (e.g. `editable-list`) automatically validate their childs upon validation, but you need to explicitly validate top-level widgets yourself before using their values.

For instance, if your form has some kind of “Apply” button, you'd iterate through all relevant input widgets in its `:notify` action, and validate each widget by calling its `:validate` property, e.g.:

```
(let ((unvalidated-widgets my-widgets)
      form-invalid)
  (while (and unvalidated-widgets (not form-invalid))
    (let ((widget (pop unvalidated-widgets)))
      (when (widget-apply input-field :validate)
        (setq form-invalid t)
        (message "Widget %s failed verification: %s"
                 (widget-get widget :tag)
                 (widget-get widget :error)))))
  (unless form-invalid
    ;; The form is valid, do whatever you want to do with its data
    ;; …
    ))
```

Where `my-widgets` is a list of widgets in your form.

Comment: Just one question, how do I get individual editable-list member widget? They are inserted/deleted automagically and I don't have any reference to them.

Comment: Why do you need the individual widgets?

Comment: so I can (widget-apply individual-child-widget :validate)

Comment: No need for that.  The list should automatically validate its children.